# Ordenar pelo nó vendas javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Como posso fazer para que o javascript ordene este array pelo nó vendas?

```
[{"codigo":"produto003059","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003062","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003067","vendas":4},{"codigo":"produto003068","vendas":1},{"codigo":"produto003070","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003071","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003073","vendas":2},{"codigo":"produto003875","vendas":3},{"codigo":"produto003879","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003881","vendas":0}]
```

Existe alguma função ou comando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ordenar arrais podes usar o [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), que passa como argumento elementos da array. Uma vez que cada elemento é um objeto tens só de dizer isso dentro do sort. Como os valores das chaves `vendas` são numeros basta usar na função do *sort* `return a.vendas - b.vendas;`

Presumo que esse array seja um JSON, por isso incluo o JSON.parse no código em baixo.

```
var vendas = '[{"codigo":"produto003059","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003062","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003067","vendas":4},{"codigo":"produto003068","vendas":1},{"codigo":"produto003070","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003071","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003073","vendas":2},{"codigo":"produto003875","vendas":3},{"codigo":"produto003879","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003881","vendas":0}]';

var ordenado = JSON.parse(vendas).sort(function(a, b){
       return a.vendas - b.vendas; 
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(ordenado)); // dá: [{"codigo":"produto003059","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003062","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003070","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003071","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003879","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003881","vendas":0},{"codigo":"produto003068","vendas":1},{"codigo":"produto003073","vendas":2},{"codigo":"produto003875","vendas":3},{"codigo":"produto003067","vendas":4}]
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8918kzvk/

Comment: Certo, e para inverter a ordem basta trocar a posição das variáveis `return b.vendas - a.vendas;`